# iOS Merge consecutive videos segments into one final video with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm working on a project that needs to record video segments and then merge these segments in one video. I'm using AVFoundation framework to do so.

The problem is that when I merge the segments, there's always a black frame or no sound between the chunks. Also, sometimes the sound is not synchronised after merging.

I've tried many options to solve this problem but didn't find a good solution. 
I've tried many solutions on Stack overflow but none of them worked.

I've also tried to use MKOVideoMerge but I still have the problem.

I've made a small View controller below that records video camera and create a new segment every 10 seconds. When the user taps on "stop", all the segments are merged and saved to camera roll :

If anyone have managed to merge two video segments without dropping frame or sound, help would be much appreciated :)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate,AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
private enum SessionSetupResult {
    case success
    case notAuthorized
    case configurationFailed
}

@IBOutlet weak var btnStartStop: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!

private let session = AVCaptureSession()
private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
private let mergeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "merge queue")
private var setupResult: SessionSetupResult = .success

private var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
lazy private var movieBufferOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
lazy private var audioBufferOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
private var movieConnection: AVCaptureConnection!
private var audioConnection: AVCaptureConnection!

private var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter! = nil
private var assetWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput! = nil
private var audioWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput! = nil

private var chunkNumber = 0
private let chunkMaxDuration = 10.0
private var chunkStartTime: CMTime! = nil
private var chunkOutputURL: URL! = nil

private var stopRecording: Bool = false

@IBAction func startStop(_ sender: Any) {
    stopRecording = true
    btnStartStop.setTitle("recording", for: .normal)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    previewView.session = session
    previewView.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .authorized:
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        sessionQueue.suspend()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { granted in
            if !granted {
                self.setupResult = .notAuthorized
            }
            self.sessionQueue.resume()
        })

    default:
        setupResult = .notAuthorized
    }

    sessionQueue.async {
        self.configureSession()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.cleanTempDirectory()

    sessionQueue.async {
        switch self.setupResult {
        case .success:
            break
        case .notAuthorized:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let changePrivacySetting = "Not authorized"
                let message = NSLocalizedString(changePrivacySetting, comment: "Alert message when the user has denied access to the camera")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Not authorized", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert OK button"),
                                                        style: .cancel,
                                                        handler: nil))

                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Settings", comment: "Alert button to open Settings"),
                                                        style: .`default`,
                                                        handler: { _ in
                                                            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }))

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        case .configurationFailed:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alertMsg = "Error"
                let message = NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: alertMsg)
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert OK button"),
                                                        style: .cancel,
                                                        handler: nil))

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func configureSession() {
    if setupResult != .success {
        return
    }

    session.beginConfiguration()
    session.sessionPreset = .high

    do {
        var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

        if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
            defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice
        } else if let backCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
            defaultVideoDevice = backCameraDevice
        } else if let frontCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) {
            defaultVideoDevice = frontCameraDevice
        }

        let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: defaultVideoDevice!)

        if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
            session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
            self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
            }
        } else {
            setupResult = .configurationFailed
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }
    } catch {
        setupResult = .configurationFailed
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    do {
        let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
        let audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)

        if session.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput) {
            session.addInput(audioDeviceInput)
        }
    } catch {

    }

    movieBufferOutput.videoSettings = [
        String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)
    ]

    if self.session.canAddOutput(movieBufferOutput) {
        self.session.addOutput(movieBufferOutput)

        if let connection = self.movieBufferOutput.connection(with: .video) {
            movieConnection = connection
            connection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight

            if connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported {
                connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .auto
            }
        }
    } else {
        setupResult = .configurationFailed
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    if self.session.canAddOutput(audioBufferOutput) {
        self.session.addOutput(audioBufferOutput)

        if let connection = self.audioBufferOutput.connection(with: .audio) {
            audioConnection = connection
        }

    } else {
        print("Could not add audio output to the session")
        setupResult = .configurationFailed
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    let queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "MediaOutputQueue")
    let audioQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "AudioOutputQueue")
    self.movieBufferOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    self.audioBufferOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioQueue)
    self.movieBufferOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    session.commitConfiguration()

    self.session.startRunning()
}

func createWriterInput(for presentationTimeStamp: CMTime) {
    self.stopRecording = false

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let outputFileName = "chunk\(chunkNumber)"
    let outputFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mp4")!)

    chunkOutputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath)
    try? fileManager.removeItem(at: chunkOutputURL)

    assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: chunkOutputURL, fileType: .mp4)

    let outputSettings: [String: Any] = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey: 1280, AVVideoHeightKey: 720]
    assetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
    assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    assetWriter.add(assetWriterInput)

    let audioSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 192000
        ] as [String : Any]

    audioWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true;
    assetWriter.add(audioWriterInput)

    chunkNumber += 1
    chunkStartTime = presentationTimeStamp

    assetWriter.startWriting()
    assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: chunkStartTime)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeRight
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeRight
}

func cleanTempDirectory() {
    let tempVideosPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    var isDirectory = ObjCBool(true)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempVideosPath, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
        return
    }

    let tempVideosURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempVideosPath)

    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: tempVideosURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.contentModificationDateKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles,.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants])

        let mp4Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp4" }.map { url in
            (url, (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]))?.creationDate ?? Date.distantPast)
            }.sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })

        for mp4 in mp4Files {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: mp4.0)
        }

    } catch {

    }
}

func getTempVideos() -> [URL] {
    let tempVideosPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    var isDirectory = ObjCBool(true)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempVideosPath, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
        return []
    }

    var videosURL: [URL] = []

    let videosUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempVideosPath)

    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: videosUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.contentModificationDateKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles,.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants])

        let mp4Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp4" }.map { url in
            (url, (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]))?.creationDate ?? Date.distantPast)
            }.sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 })

        var i = 0
        for mp4 in mp4Files {
            videosURL.append(mp4.0)
            i = i + 1

            if i > 5 {
                break
            }
        }
    } catch {
        return []
    }

    return videosURL
}

func getRecordedVideoURL() -> URL {
    var tempVideosPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()

    tempVideosPath = (tempVideosPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("videos")

    var isDirectory = ObjCBool(true)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempVideosPath, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempVideosPath), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {

        }
    }

    let outputFileName = "test-" + NSUUID().uuidString
    let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempVideosPath).appendingPathComponent(outputFileName).appendingPathExtension("mp4")

    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)

    return outputFileURL
}

func mergeVideos(urls:[URL], excludedUrl: URL, completion:@escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession?) -> ()) -> Void {
    let mainComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let soundtrackTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let assetOptions = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true]

    var insertTime = kCMTimeZero
    var audioInsertTime = kCMTimeZero
    var videos: [(asset: AVURLAsset, videoTrack: AVAssetTrack, videoDuration: CMTime)] = []

    for url in urls {
        if url.path != excludedUrl.path {
            let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options : assetOptions)

            if videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).count > 0 && videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).count > 0 {
                let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
                let videoDuration = videoTrack.timeRange.duration

                videos.append((asset: videoAsset, videoTrack: videoTrack, videoDuration: videoDuration))
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }


    var hasError: Bool = false
    for video in videos.reversed() {
        let audioTrack = video.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0]
        let audioDuration = audioTrack.timeRange.duration

        do {
            try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, video.videoDuration), of: video.videoTrack, at: insertTime)
        } catch let error {
            hasError = true
            print(error)
        }

        do {
            try soundtrackTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioDuration), of: audioTrack, at: audioInsertTime)
        } catch let error {
            hasError = true
            print(error)
        }

        insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, video.videoDuration)
        audioInsertTime = CMTimeAdd(audioInsertTime, audioDuration)
    }

    if videos.count == 0 {
        hasError = true
    }

    if !hasError {
        let outputFileURL = getRecordedVideoURL()
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mainComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        exporter?.outputURL = outputFileURL
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(exporter!)
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if connection == self.audioConnection {
        if let audioInput = self.audioWriterInput, audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            if !audioInput.append(sampleBuffer) {
                print("Error writing audio buffer");
            }
        }
    } else {
        if let videoInput = self.assetWriterInput, videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            if !videoInput.append(sampleBuffer) {
                print("Error writing video buffer");
            }
        }
    }

    if connection == movieConnection {
        let presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)

        if assetWriter == nil {
            createWriterInput(for: presentationTimeStamp)
        } else {
            let currentChunkDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeSubtract(presentationTimeStamp, chunkStartTime))

            if currentChunkDuration >= chunkMaxDuration || self.stopRecording == true {
                let chunkAssetWriter = assetWriter!
                let assetWriterInput = self.assetWriterInput
                let audioWriterInput = self.audioWriterInput
                let stopRecording = self.stopRecording

                createWriterInput(for: presentationTimeStamp)

                assetWriterInput?.markAsFinished()
                audioWriterInput?.markAsFinished()

                chunkAssetWriter.endSession(atSourceTime: presentationTimeStamp)

                chunkAssetWriter.finishWriting {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.btnStartStop.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
                    }
                    if stopRecording {
                        self.mergeQueue.async {
                            self.mergeVideos(urls: self.getTempVideos(), excludedUrl: self.chunkOutputURL!, completion: { exportSession in
                                if let exportSession = exportSession {
                                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exportSession.outputURL!)
                                    }) { saved, error in
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            if saved {
                                                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                                                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                                                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                                                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Thanks for your help :)